# temporal type IN javax.persistence (A temporal type must be specified)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jpa, eclipselink

I have this RUNTIME exception problem (using a based Object-Relational persistence solution in a relational databases and Java containers.)

```
Exception [EclipseLink-7212] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.4.2.v20130514-5956486): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: The attribute [submissionTime] from the entity class [class com.tdk.domain.Service] does not specify a temporal type. A temporal type must be specified for persistent fields or properties of type java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar.
```

But, for God's sake, the type is already **java.util.Date** !!!!

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "SUBMISSION_TIME")
    public Date getSubmissionTime() {
        return this.submissionTime;
    }
```

Here the full stacktrace

```
Exception Description: The attribute [submissionTime] from the entity class [class com.tdk.domain.Service] does not specify a temporal type. A temporal type must be specified for persistent fields or properties of type java.util.Date and java.util.Calendar.
        at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.noTemporalTypeSpecified(ValidationException.java:1443)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processTemporal(MappingAccessor.java:1829)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processJPAConverters(MappingAccessor.java:1584)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processMappingConverter(MappingAccessor.java:1652)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.MappingAccessor.processMappingValueConverter(MappingAccessor.java:1670)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.mappings.BasicAccessor.process(BasicAccessor.java:414)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataDescriptor.processMappingAccessors(MetadataDescriptor.java:1461)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.ClassAccessor.processMappingAccessors(ClassAccessor.java:1526)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.processMappingAccessors(EntityAccessor.java:1085)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.accessors.classes.EntityAccessor.process(EntityAccessor.java:645)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProject.processStage2(MetadataProject.java:1718)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.metadata.MetadataProcessor.processORMMetadata(MetadataProcessor.java:536)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processORMetadata(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:550)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.predeploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:1484)
        at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:235)
        at weblogic.persistence.BasePersistenceUnitInfo.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfo.java:452)
        at weblogic.persistence.BasePersistenceUnitInfo.initializeEntityManagerFactory(BasePersistenceUnitInfo.java:445)
        at weblogic.persistence.BasePersistenceUnitInfo.init(BasePersistenceUnitInfo.java:119)
        at weblogic.persistence.BaseJPAIntegrationProvider.createPersistenceUnitInfo(BaseJPAIntegrationProvider.java:53)
        at weblogic.persistence.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.storeDescriptors(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:420)
        at weblogic.persistence.AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.loadPersistenceDescriptors(AbstractPersistenceUnitRegistry.java:127)
        at weblogic.persistence.ModulePersistenceUnitRegistry.<init>(ModulePersistenceUnitRegistry.java:61)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppInternalModuleExtension$PersistenceExtension.setupPersistenceUnitRegistry(WebAppInternalModuleExtension.java:267)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppInternalModuleExtension$PersistenceExtension.access$400(WebAppInternalModuleExtension.java:188)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppInternalModuleExtension.prePrepare(WebAppInternalModuleExtension.java:58)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:293)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper$PrepareStateChange.next(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:285)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:42)
        at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:109)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:172)
        at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:167)
        at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:80)
        at weblogic.work.ContextWrap.run(ContextWrap.java:40)
        at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:550)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:295)
        at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:254)
```

Comment: How is that a "compilation problem" ? It is an exception AT RUNTIME.

Comment: Is the column and temporal annotations being picked up?  Turn logging to finest or All and check what EclipseLink is picking up during its deployment phase.  If you have annotations on fields and properties, only one set will get picked up.  Also check that your version of the class with the annotation is the one being picked up at runtime - it won't be the first time multiple versions of classes caused strange runtime issues.

Comment: Are you importing java.sql.Date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Chris comment was right (Is the column and temporal annotations being picked up? Turn logging to finest or All and check what EclipseLink is picking up during its deployment phase. If you have annotations on fields and properties, only one set will get picked up. Also check that your version of the class with the annotation is the one being picked up at runtime - it won't be the first time multiple versions of classes caused strange runtime issues)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should remove length = 11